# How to loop thru JSON list and save data in Django

Tags: python, json, django, database, exception

I am trying loop thru JSON list data and save into the variable 'nfts'.

**Exception Value:** string indices must be integers

**Traceback:** nft_data_id = item['nfts'][item]['nft_data_id'],

**JSON response:** {"result":{"page_count":3041,"nfts":[{"nft_id":"#-#-#-#","nft_data_id":"#-#-#-#", ...

**views.py Code:**

```
def market_data(request):
    URL = '...'
    response = requests.get(URL).json()
    nfts = response['result']
    for item in nfts:
        nft_data = NFT_attributes(
            nft_data_id = item['nfts'][item]['nft_data_id'],
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're iterating over an object instead of an array. kindly try below example

```
def market_data(request):
    URL = '...'
    response = requests.get(URL).json()
    nfts = response['result']['nfts']
    for nft in nfts:
        nft_data = NFT_attributes(
            nft_data_id = nft['nft_data_id'],
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a gentleman and a scholar!